# Parse push android. work using web - not work using mobile

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I have an App in android with push notification, using Parse library.

Push notification WORKS if I use platform web, as seen below :

[image]

But not work if I use code from mobile:

```
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("miCanal", "papa2");

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
push.setMessage(et_push.getText().toString());
push.sendInBackground();
```

**EDIT**

Tried with 'Channels" and happend the same ... :(

please help

Comment: Did you try `channels` (all lowercase)?

Comment: O yes sorry, i try it with 'channels'. Same result :(

       Maybe i cant send push to same mobile who send it ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** and choose **Push** tab. And switch **On** the option

> Client push enabled?

as shown in below image.[image]